# When stamping document - Danish characters disappear and PDF becomes invalid

Tags: itext

I have a PDF generated in Oracle BI Publisher. It contains a graph and some text. When trying to stamp the document with an image - The image gets added, but the Danish characters are destroyed.

I run iText Stamp like this:

```
static void stampPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PDF_SOURCE_FILE);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(
            PDF_STAMPED_FILE));
    Image img = Image.getInstance(WATERMARK);
    img.setAbsolutePosition(10, 100);
    PdfContentByte under = stamper.getUnderContent(1);
    under.addImage(img);
    stamper.close();
}
```

As a result, I get the following the message: *Document invalid*. But the document displays, including the added image. The Danish characters have become substituted.

All fonts has been removed from Document properties.

Has anyone seen something like this before? I have done it several times before, without problems.

Comment: I've never seen this before. Which version of iText are you using? Can you share PDF_SOURCE_FILE and WATERMARK?

Comment: I tried with newest version of iText. If you want to have a look at it, I can send you a zip containing af testcase? How can I eventually provide you with the files?

Comment: Put them on a site and provide the URL.

Comment: I would be thankful, if you could have a look: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2ltosubdxz25u1/stamptest.zip)

Comment: Hello Bruno, did you have a look at it yet?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look at the PDF and it's not an iText problem. It's a "Garbage In, Garbage Out" problem. Please open the PDF in Acrobat and analyze it for syntax errors. You'll get the following message:

[image: Garbage In, Garbage Out]

The content stream of the PDF is wrong in a way that even Acrobat can't analyze it and tell you what is wrong.

So I've looked inside the file, and when it looks as if iText can't see the page resources for the page. The page resources refer to the fonts. If iText can't see the page resources, iText can't see the fonts and they get lost in the process.

If Acrobat would allow me to "Analyze and fix", then I could create a fixed PDF and compare what was fixed. But as Acrobat can't fix the file, it's a lot of work to go through the complete file manually to find out what exactly is wrong with it. Out of curiosity, I opened the document in a text editor, and I found this:

```
4 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [ /PDF /Text ]
/Font << 
/F1 7 0 R
/F2 8 0 R
/F3 11 0 R
>>
/Shading << 
/grad0 10 0 R
/grad0#2 15 0 R
/grad1#2 17 0 R
/grad2#2 19 0 R
/grad3#2 21 0 R
/grad4#2 23 0 R
/grad5#2 25 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
```

The problem is caused by the names `/grad0#2`, `/grad1#2`, etc... Those aren't valid names. Let me quote from ISO-32000-1:

> When writing a name in a PDF file, a SOLIDUS (2Fh) (/) shall be used
>   to introduce a name. The SOLIDUS is not part of the name but is a
>   prefix indicating that what follows is a sequence of characters
>   representing the name in the PDF file and shall follow these rules:
>
> a) A NUMBER SIGN (23h) (#) in a name shall be written by using its
>   2-digit hexadecimal code (23), preceded by the NUMBER SIGN.
>
> b) Any character in a name that is a regular character (other than NUMBER
>   SIGN) shall be written as itself or by using its 2-digit hexadecimal
>   code, preceded by the NUMBER SIGN.
>
> c) Any character that is not a
>   regular character shall be written using its 2-digit hexadecimal code,
>   preceded by the NUMBER SIGN only.

In your case, you have a NUMBER SIGN (#) followed by a 1-digit number. That doesn't make any sense. The PDF is invalid.

Long story short: contact the producer of the PDF and ask him to fix the problem or never use his tools again.

Comment: I'll try to fix the template. PDF is generated using a template processed in an older version of Oracle BI Publisher.