# Getting "An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly." using ITextSharp WriteSelectedRows

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, itext, adobe-reader

I am having an issue using ITextSharp to create some tables and images that push to an MVC browser application. I think I have narrowed it down to being within adding the tables using WriteRowsSelected.

Here is my code:

PDFEngine.cs

```
  private byte[] BuildDocument(MemoryStream documentStream, IEnumerable<CustomPdfData> documents, bool addVoid, float defaultMagnification)
    {

       using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
        var finishedDocument = new Document(new Rectangle(612f, 792f));

        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(finishedDocument, stream);
        writer.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.HideWindowUI;
        writer.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.HideMenubar;

        // Open the Document for writing
        finishedDocument.Open();


        var zoomer = PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(1, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, -1, -1, defaultMagnification), writer);

        writer.SetOpenAction(zoomer);



        foreach (var document in documents)
        {


            if (document.IsNewPage)
            {
                finishedDocument.NewPage();
            }

            var results = TableEngine.BuildDocument(document);

            // Build Canvas for Table
            //PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
            //canvas.SetTextMatrix(50, 50);

            // Add each table to the canvas at specified coordinates
            for (int tableCounter = 0; tableCounter < results.ITextTables.Count; tableCounter++)
            {
                PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
                canvas.SetTextMatrix(50, 50);

                var xAxis = results.PdfTables[tableCounter].XPosition;
                var yAxis = results.PdfTables[tableCounter].YPosition;
                results.ITextTables[tableCounter].WriteSelectedRows(0, results.PdfTables[tableCounter].ColumnSize, xAxis, yAxis, writer.DirectContent);
            }




        }

        finishedDocument.Close();
        documentStream.Close();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

CheckBuilder.cs

```
  /// <summary>
    /// Used to create the fake checks needed for printing to a client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="checks">Checks to push to Builder</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] GetFakeChecks(List<HandsCheck> checks)
    {

        var doc = BuildCheck(checks, true, true);
        return CreatePdf(doc, 0.5f, false);
    }
```

DisplayChecks.cshtml

```
 <object id="WebBrowser1"  width="615" height="790"  data= "@Url.Action("GetPdfData")" type="application/pdf" />
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public FileContentResult GetPdfData()
    {
        int numberofChecks = int.Parse(Workspace.Get<string>("numberofChecks"));

     var pdfCreator = new CheckBuilder();

            var checks = GetAllChecks();
            var newList = new List<Check>();

            for (int counter = 0; counter < numberofChecks; counter++)
            {
                newList.Add(checks[counter]);
            }

            var rawData = pdfCreator.GetFakeChecks(newList);

            return File(rawData, "application/pdf");


        return null;
    }
```

The weird thing is that it seems to only happen when I add more than **1** table. Does anyone know if there are any limits per canvas? Does anyone know of any way to further debug what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Nothing jumps out to me except the passing around of `Stream` objects. I haven't ever found a good reason to do this but have seen many reasons _not_ to do it. Can you trying refactoring to only use an internal `MemoryStream` and returning a raw byte array using `MS.ToArray()`. This will also give you the benefit of not having to worrying about remembering to close the stream outside of the method and also calling a wrong stream method such as `GetBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Chris. I updated my code above to include your recommended refactoring. I think I did what you requested, but I am still getting the error. The odd thing is that the PDF always show up correct. I have also included the HTML and Controller code. Also, it seems that if I even add a second table, it throws the same error. Is there perhaps something I need to do for multiple WriteSelectedRows?

Comment: Also, if I add a Newpage call on every WriteRowsSelected, it has no issue, obviously that is not the desired effect, but I thought that might help in solving this odd issue

Comment: I would try a couple of things next. First, write the actual bytes to the server's disk and binary compare that file with what is sent to the client. Maybe MVC is sending some extra bytes (if you didn't close your connection for instance). If that works, then remove your domain-specific logic and just write a bunch of table. There isn't a limit on the number of tables in a canvas. Actually, there's no such thing as a "table" from the PDF perspective, its just text drawn at certain coordinates that happens to have coincidentally drawn near, too.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the below answer was it, but that was a great idea to step back and try things one step at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're introducing a PDF syntax error here:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.DirectContent;
canvas.SetTextMatrix(50, 50);
```

With `DirectContent`, you grab an object that allows you to write PDF syntax directly to the content stream. Immediately after that, you introduce a text state operator. This is illegal PDF syntax:

1. A text state operator is only valid inside a text object; that is: between `BT` (`BeginText()`) and `ET` (`EndText`) operators).
2. Why do you need to set the text matrix? That line doesn't make sense, because you're defining the position of the table in the `writeSelectedRows()` method.

Long story short: remove `canvas.SetTextMatrix(50, 50);` and you'll have at least one syntax error less in your PDF.

I just checked the iText codebase, and normally your code should throw an "unbalanced text state" exception. If it doesn't, either the "sanity checks" no longer work, or you're using an obsolete version of iTextSharp.

**Update**

**Comment 1:**

ISO-32000-1 defines text state as a subset of graphics state. In *graphics state*, you can change the line width, stroke color, fill color, the 'current transformation matrix' for all graphical objects, etc... You can draw lines, shapes,... in graphics state, but no text.

*Text state* is reserved for text: you change the text matrix, define the leading, font,... and you 'show' text. It is illegal to use text state operators outside a BT and ET block; for instance: changing the text matrix in graphics state only doesn't make sense as there is no text outside a BT/ET sequence. It's also illegal to nest BT and ET objects.

**Comment 2:**

Personally, I use Adobe Acrobat (the Preflight functionality) to check the syntax of a broken PDF. This is the easiest way, but that doesn't mean it's easy. Although I know ISO-32000-1 pretty well, even I don't always understand the error messages.

Sometimes Acrobat can't open a PDF file, the error is 'unknown', or Acrobat is 'unable to analyze the PDF syntax'. See for instance [When stamping document - Danish characters disappear and PDF becomes invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059440/when-stamping-document-danish-characters-disappear-and-pdf-becomes-invalid/18288964#18288964) which is a question I answered a couple of days ago. In such a case, I try using iText RUPS and I examine the PDF from the inside. In the worst case, you need to examine the PDF in a plain text editor (for instance because even RUPS can't open the file).

**Comment 3:**

When you use `writeSelectedRows()`, iText(Sharp) adds a `BT` and `ET` operator automatically. Some versions may omit the `BT` if a `BT` was already present; some versions of iTextSharp may add a `BT` when using `setTextMatrix()` if a `BT` was missing.

Long story short: iText(Sharp) sometimes tries to fix problems due to programming errors. These fixes aren't full proof, because iText(Sharp) can't always guess the intentions of a developer. As a result, the fix often fails. Morale: one should make sure not to introduce PDF syntax errors.

Comment: dude you rock.. that seems to have fixed it... I was trying to follow an example in their API guide, obviously I mixed something up. I have two questions. 1.) Can you explain a little more as to why the SetTextMatrix was an illegal syntax? Is it only because it wasn't inside a BT and ET or is there more to it? I'm new to the PDF requirements world.

Comment: 2nd question is, are there any tools or tricks to identify what the actual syntax error is that isn't so abstract / vague? I probably could have gotten somewhere quicker if there was a little more info.

Comment: one more thing... why do you think the first table got added and all subsequent ones caused the error?